# How to adjust javascript to dynamically generated checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have a bootstrap modal which is populated with checkboxes which corresponds to the number of data I retrieve from database. However I have a hard time on the javascript part of it.

Here is my code snippet for modal:

```
        <!-- Bootstrap Modal - To Add New Record -->
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="color:blue;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:blue; text-align: center;">Add Submitted Requirements</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php 
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM requirements_tbl";
    if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }

    // if query results contains rows then featch those rows 
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

             echo'<div class="checkbox ">
            <label> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="" value="" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)">
            '.$row['requirement_name'].'
            </label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmaill"> Date </label>
            <input type="date" id="datefield" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
            </div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Records Retrieve";
    }

    ?>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()">Add Record</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--- End of add modal -->
```

And Here is my javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function EnableDisableTextBox(chkbox) {
    var datefield = document.getElementById("datefield");
    datefield.disabled = chkbox.checked ? false : true;
    if (!datefield.disabled) {
        datefield.focus();
    }
}
</script>
```

when I click the the first or the last checkboxes the first datefield is the one enabling not the datefield with the corresponding checkbox

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: Where is the `function EnableDisableTextBox` and `function addRecord`? Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] with RENDERED html and relevant script. If this is not a PHP question, we do not want to see PHP

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be a comment but i have a low reputation here.

Please do not use mysql. Consider switching to either PDO or MYSQLI. Also, before displaying values from your query, consider binding them, hence the reason to switch over to either MYSQLI or PDO

Back to your question. What happens when you click on a checkbox? Does the function "EnableDisableTextBox" get called? What does your console say? any error??

Comment: Im sorry sir but it's just a project we are required to used this deprecated mysql and we are learning PDO really soon. I really appreciated your suggestion.Anyway,There is no error that I received It's just that when I click the the first or the last checkboxes the first datefield is the one enabling not the datefield with the corresponding checkbox.